# Replace <br> by \n in a textarea doesn't work in IE9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9, newline, line-breaks

My problem is simple. I am trying to replace all the `<br/>` characters from a string by `\n` and display all the resulted string in a `<textarea>` element. 
CODE:

```
textarea.innerHTML = s.innerHTML.replace(/(\r\n|[\r\n])/g, '').replace(/<br[\s\/]?>/gi, '\n');
```

Inside the textarea, I should see separated lines by "\n".
It works in any browsers, including IE6, but not in IE9. What is wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to use `value` property of `textarea`, not `innerHTML`.